# Storing data using Settings element in QML

Tags: qt, settings, qml

I have the following code (windowid in code below refers to the root element's id, Root element's width & height are same as device's width & height (i.e FullScreened)

```
 Image{
        id:tick1
        source: "../../pics/tick.png"
        width:0.0395*windowid.width
        height:0.041*windowid.height
        x: 0.4474*windowid.width 
        y:  99
        visible: false

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: tick1.y = tick1.y + 20
        }

        Settings{
            property alias yValue: tick1.y
        }


    }
```

The above code saves the y value of the image & ensure that the new y value will be stored and retrieved even if the application restarted to be the new image's y value, The above code works perfectly but if image's y value were initialized dynamically like this: `y: 0.506*windowid.height` instead of `y: 99` Settings element wont work.

It seems like when y value is dynamically used, Qt  executes everything (including the Settings element) then it starts to calculate any dynamic values found specially if that value depends on something else which is also dynamic as well (i.e device screen, width & height varies from one device to another).

How this issue can be fixed using dynamic values with the Settings element ?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the issue. Did you read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html , especially this: "A fully declarative syntax, achieved by using property aliases, comes at the cost of storing persistent settings whenever the values of aliased properties change. Normal properties can be used to gain more fine-grained control over storing the persistent settings." ?

Comment: Thnx @FrankOsterfeld for your reply, Actually the example in the url u have mentioned has no dynamic values to be stored, it saves the state as active or inactive (i.e static string), also, I have tried what u said by using property double instead of property alias but it didn't work out for me

Comment: Ah, you want y have a binding-defined default value but use the settings value instead if it is set? In your specific case, I wouldn't break the binding in onClicked then, but keep the binding and apply a yDelta that is modified in the clicked handler.