# Saving JS Object (variant or var) in settings

Tags: qml

When I write this:

```
property bool token: false

Settings {
    property alias token: root.token
}
```

and then change `token` somewhere in application to `true`, next time when I run the application `token` is `true`.

But when I write this:

```
property var token: null

Settings {
    property alias token: root.token
}
```

and change token to `{'a': 'b'}` for example, next time I run the application token is `null` like `Settings` doesn't save JS Object. Any idea what's wrong here?

Update:
It seems that problem is not with saving the js object `{'a': 'b'}`, QML saves it successfully, the problem is with `null` if I change it to `false` everything works alright. I guess it's related to this question [Storing data using Settings element in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131705/storing-data-using-settings-element-in-qml) but I don't understand why `null` is being post processed, though using `false` instead of `null` as default value for this property solves the problem I don't like it as I don't want `false` here, it's not appropriate morally, I want `null`.

Update 2:
I found my solution, setting no default value for property (not `false` nor `null`) seems to solve the issue and it seems appropriate morally like this:

```
property var token

Settings {
    property alias token: root.token
}
```

I don't understand why `null` doesn't work yet. Any explanation would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting no default value for property (not `false` nor `null`) seems to solve the issue:

```
property var token

Settings {
    property alias token: root.token
}
```